# How to decrypt cookies in Laravel 8

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-8

Recently, we upgraded our Laravel application from 5.6 to Laravel 8.18.1. We use cookie decryption in the RouteServiceProvider.php.

**HomeController.php**

> Cookie::queue("channel", "mobile", 60*24*1); // channel encrypted
> value =
> eyJpdiI6IjJVTGFzZHdEOXpjMk9VTGFFYmlSbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid0djMW9zbThWOXFQTk5aVXBDNmJBdz09IiwibWFjIjoiZGM4M2U1YTY0ZjVkNTE4NjBlNzg4NTZiNzhkNjdjYzcyODUzZWU1ZWMzNjdkNGNlMTgyZGIwNmQ4NjYzOWM3MSJ9

In Laravel 5.6, it decrypted the hash as a value directly.

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
$encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class);
$channel_cookie = $encrypter->decrypt(Cookie::get('channel')); // result "mobile"
```

In Laravel 8.18.1, it decrypted the hash as a value with a vertical bar.

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
$encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class);
$channel_cookie = $encrypter->decrypt(Cookie::get('channel')); // result "a86aa854d5e61e2873acd30373b6725e36fba671|mobile"
$channel_cookie = explode("|",$channel_cookie)[1]; // result mobile
```

Is this a safe solution to decrypt cookies in Laravel 8?

Comment: Did you find out how to do it better? It's a really weird way of decrypting, but I can't find another solution too.

Answer (score 2):

If the cookie value is not sensitive, you can disable encryption for it by following the documentation:

[Cookies & Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#cookies-and-encryption).

```php
<?php

// app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as Middleware;

class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        'user_locale',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could found the reason of your issue in this security bulletin about prefixing cookies in laravel.

https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-cookie-security-releases

The code were laravel do this operation is in framework source file linked below

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieValuePrefix.php

In our scenario we have realized something similar the original code, in two words: the cookie name is encrypted and added to cookie value with a `|` as separation char.

Comment: This is very helpful context, but doesn't answer the question @xyonme asked. Is there any other context about how to remove the pipe in a less 'explosive' way?

Comment: There's definitely an API for removing the prefix: \Illuminate\Cookie\CookieValuePrefix::remove($decryptedCookie), but that assume's you've decrypted the cookie yourself first (hence my choice of variable name). Instead, you can let the API decrypt the cookie and remove the prefix for you: \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::get($cookie), and you'll see that you're going to get the same value.