# Extra string & pipe character in Laravel Cookies

Tags: cookies, laravel-6

In a Laravel 6x project I'm working on I'm setting a cookie with:

`Cookie::queue('remember_me', json_encode(['uid' => $user->id, 'token' => $token]),2628000);`

I'm reading the cookie and decrypting it with:

`$cookies = Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('remember_me'),false);`

This works well, except that the value of $cookies has an extra pre-pended string and a | delimiter in it:

`e80cd502fec2a621b624ead8eb1cc91a2e94846b|{"uid":872,"token":"l1214065120208k"}`

I can work with that obviously to get what I need but I have been unable to find anything on why that string and | are being prepended to the cookie.  Any explanation or documentation link?

I did find another thread here with a similar question but no answer:

[How to decrypt cookies in Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247093/how-to-decrypt-cookies-in-laravel-8)

I also found a thread suggesting that Laravel 8 adds the session_id to the cookie string.  Is that what I'm seeing here?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

This value looks to be an HMAC-SHA1 of the cookie name with `v2` appended to the end.

This logic is implemented in the [CookieValuePrefix](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/00fa9c04aed10d68481f5757b89da0e6798f53b3/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieValuePrefix.php) class in Laravel and the code looks like so:

```
public static function create($cookieName, $key)
{
    return hash_hmac('sha1', $cookieName.'v2', $key).'|';
}
```

This is used in the [`EncryptCookies` middleware](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/00fa9c04aed10d68481f5757b89da0e6798f53b3/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php#L145-L151) when encrypting and decrypting accordingly. The relevant source code is:

```
// in decrypt() function
$hasValidPrefix = strpos($value, CookieValuePrefix::create($key, $this->encrypter->getKey())) === 0;
$request->cookies->set(
        $key, $hasValidPrefix ? CookieValuePrefix::remove($value) : null
);

// in encrypt() function
$this->encrypter->encrypt(
        CookieValuePrefix::create($cookie->getName(), $this->encrypter->getKey()).$cookie->getValue(),
        static::serialized($cookie->getName())
)
```

I put this logic into a [CyberChef page here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B%27option%27:%27Base64%27,%27string%27:%27Mp4QBJMslIoNbch25SoiMzdQ%2BhRxdnQ8nKWl4wz0Ca4%3D%27%7D,%27SHA1%27)&input=cmVtZW1iZXJtZXYy) to test it out with some local cookies I had and verify the output matches and it did. If you go there and plug in your app key (preferable a disposable one) you should see it output the hash value you have in your question.