# How can I disable Cookie Value Prefix in my Laravel apps

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am using multiple laravel version like 6.x, 8.x in my local machine.

In all my laravel apps I observed that laravel is appending encrypted cookie key name in cookie value.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/00fa9c04aed10d68481f5757b89da0e6798f53b3/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieValuePrefix.php

for example
if my cookie name is `laravel_session` and cookie value is `xyz` then laravel is adding `laravel_sessionv2|xyz` in the cookie value after encrypting it.

something like `e8617029d2d9cf4ea049a140afea94c6af4a5aa3|1jQEpznJy64PVNSOgPKClzhLMUj4gn34zRRpwdW9`

here's a sample that I created at Cyberchef
[https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B'option':'Base64','string':'5Q6/BDLAS2MF0fN9FmMvkSuEvC71P%2BnvwkXw/jzvbUo%3D'%7D,'SHA1')&input=bGFyYXZlbF9zZXNzaW9udjI](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B%27option%27:%27Base64%27,%27string%27:%275Q6/BDLAS2MF0fN9FmMvkSuEvC71P%2BnvwkXw/jzvbUo%3D%27%7D,%27SHA1%27)&input=bGFyYXZlbF9zZXNzaW9udjI)

This is common in all my Laravel apps. But in my peers machine they are not getting such prefix. they have only cookie value but without prefix. We all are using same source code but somehow only I am getting the prefix.

this leads me to the question How can I disable it in my machine.

The same question was asked before on SO but didn't answered how to disable it

[Extra string & pipe character in Laravel Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66954858/extra-string-pipe-character-in-laravel-cookies)

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by upgrading my laravel/framework version to 6.20.44.
[image]

If this didn't solve your problem then tell me something :)