# Laravel 8 Cookie retreiving wrong value

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

we recently upgraded from older Laravel to Laravel 8 and cookies doesn't seem to work anymore.

We have dynamically created links for translating website:

```
  <a href="{{ URL::to('/translate') }}/{{ $language->language_code }}">
```

In this route->function we create a cookie:

```
public function cookie_translate($id){

  Cookie::queue('translate', $id, 3000);
  return Redirect::route('index')->withCookie('translate');

}
```

And in AppServiceProvider.php we retreive cookie:

```
if(!empty(Cookie::get('translate'))){
  $translate = Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('translate'), false);
  $lang_title['view'] = Languages::getLanguage($translate);
  $language_title = $lang_title['view']->language_name;
}
```

But since upgrading, we keep getting this error:

> ErrorException Attempt to read property "language_name" on null

Debugging we found out that, cookie get, brings in wrong value:

```
39d3fc269f0567accb5452b937f862ca771d4fc6|nl
```

It should be only `nl`

When researching, I only found posts from couple years ago, that no one has responded and have no positive answer.

Comment: I don’t know much about Laravel, and you’ve probably already [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68217874/231316), but cookies are prefixed with a hash of the cookie’s name, for reasons [explained here](https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-cookie-security-releases). I’m guessing you need to activate a middleware? Or just trim the first 41 characters off of it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to decrypt the cookie's contents after getting them? Pretty certain that cookies are automatically encrypted / decrypted by the EncryptCookies middleware which is automatically enabled for web requests.